# Upload public file to dropbox from iOS App without auth

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

Am writing an iPhone App in which I want to upload a text file from the iOS App to somewhere & I thought of using dropbox for it. I will upload the file to my dropbox ID from the App (i.e. the user won't be required to authenticate with his/her dropbox credentials). Is this possible? Dropbox API (I even tried GDrive API) asks for auth ; how do I give my dropbox credentials through code & upload the file to my dropbox account?

Answer (score 1):

**You must need Auth,otherwise in which account the file gets uploaded??**

Comment: I will upload to my account in dropbox (i.e. the account that I have for the app)

Comment: @Jean, then it will just open the app & asking for Permission (But don't ask for re-enter the id/password) to upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any other means to accomplish this except through OAuth.

Please refer to [this framework](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/ios) that enables your app to access files from Dropbox without having to worry about the complexities of implementing a file browser, OAuth, or managing uploads and storage.